# Javascript click event doesn't work on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, onclick

I have created a website using backbone.js, jquery and pure javascript. In my sidemenu I have a list with some countries. If you click a country a sublist opens with cities, And if you click on a city another list expands below it filled with museums. Each museum has a checkbox next to it. So when you open the list all the checkboxes are filled and all the museums are shown in my page. When you close the list the checkboxes are unckecked and the list toggles up. It works fine with every pc browser and with all the android devices I have checked. 
But it doen't work on Ipad. Every time I click on a city it may check or uncheck the checkboxes, toggle or not the list e.t.c. Its works pretty weird.

```
events: {
        "tap li.category a.check-toggle" : "toggleAllMuseums"
    },


toggleAllMuseums: function(e){.....}
```

html

```
<li class="category">
    <a class="toggle check-toggle">London</a>
    <ul class="collapsible checkbox">
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> London Museum
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is a sample of my code.. The problem is only in iPad..

Answer (score 0):

it's a know issue for ipad

A workaround is consider the click as activating/hovering an element: http://www.danwellman.co.uk/fixing-jquery-click-events-for-the-ipad/